# Minimum Context for Testing SpringCloudStream Consumer

Tags: rabbitmq, junit5, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to create junit tests an application that makes use of Spring Cloud Stream to recieve events from RabbitMQ. In other application I generally import `spring-cloud-stream-test-support` and `spring-rabbit-test` and annotate the test class with `@SpringBootTest` and we're good to go. However, `@SpringBootTest` loads the entire application context which is not ideal in this application as it is quite large and would require the mocking of too many beans which are irrlevant to the test. Therefore, I tried limiting the context by specifying the classes I want loaded as follows:
`@SpringBootTest(classes = {MessageProcessor.class, Consumer.class})`. It seems like this is not enough as I'm getting a `Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel` error.

So my question is, what are the minimum classes that need to be included in the context to test SpringCloudStream/RabbitMQ consumer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error it seems that the bare minimum for the tests to work is the following:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MessageProcessor.class, Consumer.class,
    org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BindingServiceConfiguration.class,
    org.springframework.cloud.stream.test.binder.TestSupportBinderConfiguration.class
})
```